# What are the actual phases in creating a website?

Tags: php, html

I've learned a bit of web programming through books and tutorials I found online and I'm able to design and embed PHP into my HTML code. The following are the tools I'm using: XAMPP, Dreamweaver, Notepad++.

As you know, I'm creating a localhost, opening a folder, name it something and put my .html and .php files into it.

I have partially created some pages functions etc and I have the following questions:

When we have all the .php .html files what do I have to do so that it works actually on the web and not on the localhost?

Also, let's say that I have two different functions in different .php files. How am I able to call them via the HTML file using the "include" method? I am only able to use the include method when I try to call one function but when I type in the second include method to be able to call the other function too I get an error, so am I doing something wrong?

And if this is possible is it the right way of doing the things? and how what is better? include or require?

Comment: It's pretty much the same as running it on your local machine; you drop your files in the public_html (or htdocs) directory

Comment: I didn't quite understand your include/require issue. This should work, but I'd recommend asking another question here with a sample of your code. It's best also to ask one question per post if you can, so that the question retains broad relevance to a wide readership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike says, deploying a site is similar to running things on your local machine. You should firstly choose your hosting:

- Shared: you have limited permissions on the server, but everything is maintained for you by the host, and you share the CPU/RAM in the server. There is sometimes security isolation problems between customers with this option, depending on the web server configuration
- Dedicated: a full machine which you have root permissions on. You can have this maintained for you at extra cost, or you can do maintenance and reboots yourself
- VPS: root access to a virtual dedicated server, costing a fraction of the dedicated option. Also available in maintained and DIY modes
- Cloud: like VPS but sits in a server farm, so you can reconfigure compute capacity (CPU, RAM, disk) at will, and machines can be moved from one server to another transparently in order to provide fault tolerance

Also, there are a few things you can do to make deployments easier:

- Commit your code to version control
- Set up config file(s) that applies the correct settings (e.g. database credentials) depending on the server/domain name found in `$_SERVER` or environment variables in your Apache config. This can be committed as normal files in your version control
- Set up SSH keys so that you can access your live server, and pull the latest copy of your source code, without entering passwords
- Create a script to do a one-click database copy from live (or live backups) to your local machine. This is useful if you find a bug in live and you want to create the live situation in your local environment. If you have a large database (several GB) it is useful to `rsync` the new SQL backup against the old one copied locally - this can really speed up the transfer of the newer version
- Deploy using your version control. So for `git` your deployment it is usually `git pull`
- If you want to improve on this, you can do automated deployments with Capistrano, Puppet or Chef

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a website on the world wide web, you need a [server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) that hands out your web pages to visiting guests. There are tons of hosting services that make this easy, just look up "web hosting services." You'll want to pick a name to register (like google.com), once you purchase the name, you will probably want to place your files (index.html/php is generally the landing page) on the server. This can be done with an [FTP client](https://filezilla-project.org/) or sometimes with a control panel directly associated with your site.

This whole process can cost from like 9$ to multiple 100$ depending on what you purchase and the length of time you choose to keep it. My site costs me about 10$/month, for the name and hosting.

This is simplified, if you want to read more, [this looks like a decent overview](http://www.thesitewizard.com/gettingstarted/startwebsite.shtml).

Comment: Virtual hosting is [really _really_ cheap](http://lowendbox.com/) these days, and same with shared hosting too, I expect.